# npm update from private git repo on BitBucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bitbucket

I have a node module hosted on Bitbucket. I have linked to it like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "my_module": "git+https://<TEAM-API-KEY>:x-oauth-basic@bitbucket.org/team_name/repo_name.git"
}
```

This works fine for initial `npm install`, but `npm update` does not pull the latest commit on the master branch. Basically, npm update does nothing regardless of changes to the repo. According to [this thread](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1727) on the npm github page, this issue was fixed and closed.

I have tried adding #commit-ish information to the URL and it still won't update to either the explicit commit I reference or to the latest commit in the branch I reference.

I have tried updating the version number of the module, and `npm update` still ignores it.

I am using npm v2.5.1. What am I doing wrong?